# where to keep css files in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

for a good practice,In which directory we keep multiple `css` files like ( `style.min.css` , `font.awesome.css`) in **Angular4**

[image: Angular]

Comment: Global CSS styles / files should be placed in the assets folder, just like images and other resource files.

Comment: I did the same, and it work fine when we give its reference in `index.html` but when I tried to  register it in `angular-cli.json` then it showing me error at the time of build.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use webpack and it`s plugins like css-loader and style-loader
then import them in you appComponent.ts:
for example:

```
import '/assets/style.css';
```

css file will load and inject automatically to page when you run webpack build.